# Facing problem in Algo trading due to Symbol difference in trading view and my trading account

Tags: pine-script

I am Nagendra Singh , I am using Algo trading by trading view mostly symbols are same in trading vie and my trading account.
But some Symbols are different in trading view and my trading account due to this I am unable to get the signal to my trading account, it showing symbol error.

example there is a symbol 'M_M' on trading view and 'M&M' in my trading account.

I would like to know how to solve this problem, is there any pine coding is available which can convert the symbol during sending the signal to trading account.

Look forward for your support
Regards
Nagendra Singh

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, you need to create a user input for the symbol name and manually type it.

```
symbol_name = input.string("", "Symbol name")
```

Use `symbol_name` for your alerts and `syminfo.tickerid` or `syminfo.ticker` for the rest of the code.